# Htaccess - Remove end of URL when it contains a word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the ?search query and the end of the URL, provided the URL contains the word "design".

For example, if the htaccess file contained this rule, it will transform:

```
https://www.example.com/designs/brandicons/Dinodento/?search=dino
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/designs/brandicons/Dinodento/
```

but would **not** touch:

```
https://www.example.com/product/search/?search=dino
```

..as it doesn't contain the word "design".

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search= [NC]
RewriteRule ^designs/.*$ /$0? [L,R=301,NC]
```

It will match and URI starting with `/designs/` that has `?search=` query string. In replacement `/$0?` will strip off query string.